# CSS: nth-of-type(2) is not being applied to class

Tags: css

[Example page](http://test.doig.com.au/front-page.html)

The bottom right div containing "Student Visas" I thought would be affected by CSS:

```
.front-page-widget-portrait2:nth-of-type(2) .second-half {
    height: 240px;
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 40.28436018% 40px 0 40px;
    position: relative;
}
.front-page-widget-portrait2:nth-of-type(2) .second-half img {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 49px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[image]

It is contained in the 2nd div of class `front-page-widget-portrait2`, but `.front-page-widget-portrait2:nth-of-type(2)` is not being applied.

Can you see why not? Help appreciated.

Comment: FYI `nth-of-type()` doesn't respect classes.

Comment: Oh, didn't know that @Mr.Alien. Can you recommend an alternative way of targeting?

Comment: Give me some time.. I am out right now ;)

Comment: Ok, so the only `img` tag am seeing in your Student Visas element is for the green caret, is that the thing you are trying to target?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your markup is something like this

```
<div></div> <!-- Some more div elements around on the same level -->
<div class="front-page-widget-portrait2"></div>
<div class="front-page-widget-portrait2"></div>
<div></div> <!-- Some more div elements around on the same level -->
```

Instead of this, try wrapping your `front-page-widget-portrait2` inside another `div` like

```
<div></div> <!-- Some more div elements around on the same level -->
<div class="front-page-widgets">
  <div class="front-page-widget-portrait2"></div>
  <div class="front-page-widget-portrait2"></div>
</div>
<div></div> <!-- Some more div elements around on the same level -->
```

Now, you can use a selector like

```
.front-page-widgets > div:nth-of-type(2) .second-half {
  /* Styles goes here */
}
```

Let me break down the selector to explain to you how it works. We first select the wrapper element that is `front-page-widgets` (we just created a new one). Moving further, we use `>` which selects immediate children to wrapper element i.e `div` with a `class` of `front-page-widget-portrait2`. But as I already mentioned that `nth-` won't respect classes, so using it in the selector makes no sense. Lastly I use `.second-half` which selects the second block in your second widget.

Comment: Thanks again, visitor from beyond... :-)